# How do I obtain the Point Spread Function (PSF) of a ground telescope?

Tags: astronomy, observational-astronomy

I have some galaxy kinematic maps (velocity maps) extracted from Integral Field Spectroscopy (IFS) datacubes. Like any observation data coming from a ground telescope, these velocity maps include (ie: are convolved with) a Point Spread Function (PSF).

- How can someone obtain the PSF for some data? Can someone provide me with a list of all different techniques?
- I read somewhere that a way to obtain the PSF is to observe a point light source and use that as your PSF. Is this correct? It doesn't sound correct to me because in between observations the telescope may move, so the atmospheric contribution to the PSF will be different, right?
- Is it possible to obtain the PSF by just processing the observation data?

Comment: Often the PSF can be obtained from whoever operates the telescope, or from the team that set up the instrument. Which facility are you using?

Comment: At the moment I am using data from the GHASP and CALIFA surveys that I found online.